# R replace only specific values and keep all others in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, case

my code looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
 subject sex control q1 q2
       1   M     7.9  1  1
       2   F     6.3  2  3
       3   F     9.5  3  1
       4   M    11.5  7  6
')

df %>% mutate_all(~case_when(
                              . == 1 ~ 7,
                              . == 7 ~ 1,
                              TRUE ~ . )
                  )
```

I want to replace all 1 with 7 and vice versa but keep everything else.

The error states:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `subject`.
> i `subject = (structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`.
> x must be a double vector, not an integer vector.

A solution indicates
`TRUE ~ as.numeric(as.character(.)) )`
works, but then the sex colum is NA

How can I fix this?

Edit (add):
A suggestion was to use nested if-else, which would work, but I really hope  there is a better solution than:
`df %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(. == 1, 7, ifelse(. == 7, 1, .)))`

imagine a long list of values to be replaced.

Comment: It's not unreasonable that you get `NA` for all values of `Sex`.  What numeric values would you like `M` and `F` to be mapped to?  The approach you've taken assumes the values in your character columns are string versions of numerics - `11.5`, `7` and the like.  That just isn't true for `Sex`.  You need to give R a little bit of help.  Also, note that `mutate_all` and its siblings have been superseded by `across`.

Comment: sure, mutate_all can be replaced by mutate(across(everything()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `mutate_at()` or `mutate_if()` to selectively choose which columns to apply the transformation to.

```
df %>% mutate_at(c(3:5), ~case_when(
   . == 1 ~ 7,
   . == 7 ~ 1,
   TRUE ~ as.numeric(.))
)

df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~case_when(
   . == 1 ~ 7,
   . == 7 ~ 1,
   TRUE ~ as.numeric(.))
)
```

Edit:
a non-deprecated version without mutate_if would be:

```
df %>% mutate(
      across(
        where(is.numeric), 
          ~case_when(
           . == 1 ~ 7,
           . == 7 ~ 1,
           TRUE ~ as.numeric(.)
          )
      )
)
```

Comment: this looks like a really good solution (the lower one) but is superseded by mutate across.. can you give an example which is not depricated already

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("q"), 
                ~ ifelse(. == 1, 7,
                         ifelse(. == 7, 1, .))
                ))
  subject sex control q1 q2
1       1   M     7.9  7  7
2       2   F     6.3  2  3
3       3   F     9.5  3  7
4       4   M    11.5  1  6
```

A column-name independent solution is this:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.integer), 
                ~ ifelse(. == 1, 7,
                         ifelse(. == 7, 1, .))
  ))
```

Comment: I want a more generic solution where the column names doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

I would use a nested `ifelse()` call along with `lapply()` here:

```
cols <- c("q1", "q2")  # or whatever columns you want
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) ifelse(x == 1, 7, ifelse(x == 7, 1, x)))
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution but I think it's not the best

Comment: Actually, if the only requirement be to swap just two values, it is pretty optimal.  If you need to map multiple values, then I might look into using `case_when()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `mutate_all` in a function, to skip the characters e.g.

```
custom_fun <- function(x){
  if(is.integer(x)|is.numeric(x)){
    case_when(
      x == 1 ~ 7,
      x == 7 ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ as.numeric(x) 
    )
  }else{
    x
  }
} 

df %>% mutate_all(custom_fun)
```

Comment: this looks like a working solution, but honestly R, you can't be that complicated!

Comment: No worries, my dplyr skills aren't the best so I expect there is a neater way of doing it